# Best approach for view model creation to handle single entity and list - return IQuerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Looking for input on the best approach/pattern to meet the following requirement for a view model class:

- Converts an IQueryable from a repository select to a IQueryable view model query <-- Works fine
- Converts a single instance of a db entity to a view model instance <-- is not working, returns NULL
- Both use a single method to map db entity to view model properties to avoid mapping replication

Example of what I am attempting, but it is not working...and seems maybe a bit of a hack:

```
public class WorkOrderDependencyViewModel : IEntity, IViewModel<WorkOrderDependency, WorkOrderDependencyViewModel>
{
    public int Id { get; set; } }
    public int WorkOrderHeaderId { get; set; }
    public int POHeaderId { get; set; }      
    public decimal RemainQty { get; set; }

    //Re-use this mapping logic for both converting a query and converting a single db entity instance. Used by Kendo Grids
    public IQueryable<WorkOrderDependencyViewModel> ConvertClassQueryToViewModelQuery(IQueryable<WorkOrderDependency> entityQuery)
    {
        var viewModelResultQuery = entityQuery
            .Select(x => new WorkOrderDependencyViewModel()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                WorkOrderHeaderId = x.WorkOrderHeaderId,
                POHeaderId = x.PODetail.POHeaderId,
                RemainQty = x.PODetail.QtyOrdered - x.PODetail.QtyReceived
            }
        );

        return viewModelResultQuery;
    }

    //convert single instance of db entity to view model, but use existing mapping logic from above method
    public WorkOrderDependencyViewModel ConvertClassToViewModel(WorkOrderDependency entity)
    {
        var entityList = new List<WorkOrderDependency>();
        entityList.Add(entity);
        var viewModel = ConvertClassQueryToViewModelQuery(entityList.AsQueryable()).FirstOrDefault() as WorkOrderDependencyViewModel;
        return viewModel; <------ viewModel is NULL
    }
}
```

Why is viewModel returning NULL?

Comment: is there a typo in your code? You are projecting your entity to a WorkOrderDependencyListViewModel instead of a WorkOrderDependencyViewModel

Comment: Yes, thanks, but it was just a typo in me pasting info in the question, not in the true source code, so that is not the root of the problem.

Comment: I would probably put a breakpoint and find out which part of the line is null. e.g. is entity null, is your ConvertClassQueryToViewModelQuery() returning null? Also check if calling a FirstOrDefault() gives you the correct type. It will return null if the cast to WorkOrderDependencyViewModel fails

Comment: @ChadRichardson - Did you look at AutoMapper? I used it for Entity -> ViewModel conversion and vice versa. http://automapper.org/

Answer (score 1):

This would be a much shorter and easier way to do this if you don't need IQueryable

```
public WorkOrderDependencyViewModel ConvertClassToViewModel(
    WorkOrderDependency entity)
{
    return new WorkOrderDependencyViewModel 
    {
        Id = entity.Id,
        WorkOrderHeaderId = entity.WorkOrderHeaderId,
        POHeaderId = entity.PODetail.POHeaderId,
        RemainQty = entity.PODetail.QtyOrdered - entity.PODetail.QtyReceived
    };
}
```

**Edit**
If you are using this as part of a linq query, maybe you can use Automapper or a func like this

```
private static readonly Expression<Func<WorkOrderDependency, WorkOrderDependencyViewModel>> AsViewModel =
    entity => new WorkOrderDependencyViewModel
        {
            Id = entity.Id,
            WorkOrderHeaderId = entity.WorkOrderHeaderId,
            POHeaderId = entity.PODetail.POHeaderId,
            RemainQty = entity.PODetail.QtyOrdered - entity.PODetail.QtyReceived
        };
```

You would use it in your query like this

```
public IQueryable<WorkOrderDependencyViewModel> GetViewModel()
{
    return repository.WorkOrderDependencies  // change to suit your query needs
                     .Select(AsViewModel);

}
```

Comment: Yes, but I do need IQueryable as that is what I am passing back to a Kendo Grid and with an IQueryable, it manipulates the query further automatically based on user actions on the grid like sorting and filtering.

Comment: @ChadRichardson Can you see my edit to work with linq queries?

Comment: ok, I am trying this now for the IQueryable...but how do you use this function to convert a single instance of an entity? - Sorry if this is obvious, but I am new to functions.

Comment: I suppose you could do what you did above and add the entity to a list, and then call return yourlist.Select(AsViewModel);